# How to make inside not dashed?

Tags: tikz-styles

I'm trying to make a finite state automata where inside one node it contains another FSA, but the inside and the node itself appears dashed, which I don't want. I only want the outer node to be dashed.

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,node distance=2.8cm] 
    \node[state, dashed] (A) {$
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,node distance=2.8cm]

        \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=black]

        \node[state] (A)              {$A$};
        \node[state] (B) [right of=A] {$B$};

        \draw (A) to[loop left] node[auto] {$f$} (A);
        \draw (B) to[bend left] node[auto] {$f$} (A);
        \draw (A) to[bend left] node[auto] {$g$} (B);
        \draw (B) to[loop right] node[auto] {$g$} (B);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    $};

    \draw (A) node[auto] {} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But the effect of the tikzstyle is not shown.

Comment: Can you add a full working example? That start with `\documentclass{}` and ends with `\end{document}`. It would make it easier to answer :)

Comment: You can't embed `tikzpicture` environments. Can you post an image of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution that avoids the nested `tikzpicture` (that is known for problems).

The inner nodes are drawn first. Then the outer node is placed using the fitting library `fit`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,node distance=2.8cm]
  \begin{scope}
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=black]

    \node[state] (A)              {$A$};
    \node[state] (B) [right of=A] {$B$};

    \draw (A) to[loop left] node[auto] (tmp1) {$f$} (A);
    \draw (B) to[bend left] node[auto] (tmp2) {$f$} (A);
    \draw (A) to[bend left] node[auto] (tmp3) {$g$} (B);
    \draw (B) to[loop right] node[auto] (tmp4) {$g$} (B);
  \end{scope}

  \node[
    state,
    dashed,
    fit=(tmp1) (tmp2) (tmp3) (tmp4),
    inner sep=0pt, % The padding is already provided by the inner
                   % annotation nodes.
  ] (A) {}; % Overwrites the previous (A), or a different name can be used.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Another advantage is that is it now possible to easily access the inner nodes, for example, to draw arrows from or to an inner node.

Comment: Nice. I followed OP's approach. But this is much cleaner

Answer (score 4):

So, the issue here is that when you write `\node[dashed]`, it automatically draws that format, "dashed", down to anything that is inside that environment.

An easy way to reverse that is to simply add the word "solid" on the tikzpicture that you have inside the node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,node distance=2.8cm] 
    \node[state, dashed] (A) {$
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,node distance=2.8cm, solid]

        \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=black]

        \node[state] (A)              {$A$};
        \node[state] (B) [right of=A] {$B$};

        \draw (A) to[loop left] node[auto] {$f$} (A);
        \draw (B) to[bend left] node[auto] {$f$} (A);
        \draw (A) to[bend left] node[auto] {$g$} (B);
        \draw (B) to[loop right] node[auto] {$g$} (B);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    $};

    \draw (A) node[auto] {} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: You can find the information on the [tikz-pgf manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf), on section 15 "Actions on Paths"